# Input onchange with Angular2

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I try to detect on change with dart. Example html:

```
<div>
    <input id="photoUpload" type="file" name="photo" (onchange)="update()" multiple>
</div>
```

Dart:

```
@Component(
    selector: "photo-upload-dialog", templateUrl: "photo_upload_dialog.html")
class PhotoUploadDialog {


  update() async {
    print('Changed!');
  }
}
```

But nothing in a console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` is the default event handler name, not the event name.

Use instead

```
(change)="update()"
```