# how do I monitor for change in angularjs 4

Tags: angular

I tried this first since it was mentioned here on stackoverflow

```
<input ng-change="action()" type="text" [(ngModel)]="tempNode.cost_center">
```

but that did not work since its probably for angularjs 1, so I next tried

```
<input ngChange="action()" type="text" [(ngModel)]="tempNode.cost_center">
```

well I got same results with both, action method is not called. How do I listen for change inside input text box? I would like to listen to when user inputs new characters but I cant find anything with ngChange in angular4 documentation and it seems that most of questions how to do this mention ng-change which I think is angularjs 1 since it does not work when I try it and it looks like angularjs syntax.

Comment: In angular4, try (change)="action()".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input onchange with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291410/input-onchange-with-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngModelChange` :

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="tempNode.cost_center" (ngModelChange)='yourFunction()'>
```

**OR**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tempNode.cost_center" (change)='yourFunction()'>
// OR
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tempNode.cost_center" (input)='yourFunction()'>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to listen to when user inputs new characters

You can use `(keyup)="action()"` for this.